# GitLab container does not communicate with GitLab Container Registry container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, container-registry

I use [this docker-compose file](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/blob/master/docs/docker-compose-registry.yml) to create a GitLab installation along with the GitLab Container Registry enabled.

All containers start nicely, but when I try to access the container registry via a new GitLab project, I get a 500 error.

From Kitematic, in the registry container logs I see this

`http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.99.1:54873: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake`

I am not an expert in security, but from my research I think it has to do with the self-signed certificate that GitLab expects.

Is this the problem? How should I proceed?